# Mystical Creatures living together

Tags: mythical-creatures

What laws would need to be in place in an overarching ruling society that maintains peace in all mythical creatures? 
I am looking at including as many Mythical creatures as possible, and so the overarching society has to be able to work with all of them, the main city is a culture hub and full of technology from all Mystics. Most of the time it is the difference in technology uses and the absence of Dragon Riders that causes strife, as many brushes between species are not healthy. Sub-species groups are seen as the minority, the High Council acts as the supreme court and deals with interspecies problems.

Comment: Welcome to WorldBuilding! This feels really broad. What mythical creatures are we talking about here specifically? There are a lot of different mythical creatures and I am pretty sure that most people don't know all of them. Could you narrow this down? And what defines peace for you? Are we talking about mythical creatures that are living in fictional countries and should not wage war against each other?

Comment: What kind of mythical creatures are we talking about? Baba yaga? Anansi? Witte wieven? Also what technological level is our society? The needs of the law depend on how advanced it is,

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding.  This is a very broad question.  Fantasy authors have been developing different sets of rules for "keeping the peace" for literally centuries, and each author comes up with their own solutions.  You might try posting the question in [the sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/635/2252) to get some help refining the question into something we can answer here.

Comment: Any Mythical creature you can think of

Comment: Suggest you narrow your Q by picking two species that don't get along in your world, and give us enough world description that we're not left guessing about relevant aspects in your world.  And (because I cannot resist), a quote from Ghostbuster:  "Human sacrifice, dogs and cats living together – mass hysteria."  (Wasn't there something about 'without a license as well? ;-)

Comment: Currently looking at broad as I am new at making a society, and I have no clue as to how I want species to interact as of yet. All I know is that they have a UN representative, so there are connections to the greater world, but I don't know how I want the many species to interact. All I know is that the dragons and their riders tend to be seen as nobility.

Comment: Another twist you might consider is what kind of peace you are looking for.  Presuming you intend this for a book or other work, you will want to create the kind of peace that suits you as a person and your style.  Some people prefer to use a simplistic concept of peace and laws, where the theory is that if you have the right set of laws, peace lasts forever.  Others prefer to have peace that's in a precarious balance, barely restrained by the laws.  Others like to write about how laws are just pieces of paper, and real peace comes from within.

Comment: You should wait to accept an answer: the normal practice is to wait at least a day, in case a better answer turns up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Systems of laws are pretty dang dense.

You'll have to get specific so we can answer this question, otherwise it's so broad that many answers could be thesis long.

Pick out specific problems that you foresee for us to solve. That's more likely to get an answer.

But, the basics should be clear.

There are certain laws (though there may be exceptions and differing punishments) that you can find anywhere.

1) Murder is bad.

2) Stealing is bad.

3) Rape is bad.

4) Hitting another being is bad.

How bad these things are and under what circumstances they might be acceptable, are frankly, up to you and the world you build.

Comment: I'm not sure if #4 fits in with the other three.  It feels more like wishful thinking than anything else.

Answer (score 0):

**They have to classify creatures considering sentience/intelligence/sapience.**

Creatures being able to judge the consequences of their actions and feel feelings should be full right citiziens, while monsters being similar in intelligence to animals should be treated as animals.

However, many interesting and potentially problematic border cases would arise. Intelligent animals, humanoids with reduced sapience, beings having one fatal flaw which hinders their integration into the society... (like satyrs, who are normal, except their inclination to rape nymphs.) So they need a mechanism to decide who has civil rights, who can be enslaved, who has rights but is under tutelage of more responsible creatures...

**After this is solved, you can use the laws of any existing society.**

Of course, minor modifications are needed. They might introduce the crime of stealing life-giving magical artifacts in the Penal Code (if using modernish law), or determine the weregild you have to pay after killing a dragon Rider, Kappa, Golden Deer or Norse Ice Giant... (If they adopt old Anglo-Saxon law)

But these are details, which can not  be answered without more information